# How to restrict edition on a Word paragraph by modifying the OOXML files

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to protect (or restrict edition) a Word paragraph programmatically using PHP (specifically [PhpWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), but that's irrelevant) by modifying the XML files inside the `*.docx` file.

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to manage editing restriction with OOXML like:

- Protecting specific paragraph or lines of text
- Protecting document properties (title, author, and custom properties too)
- Setting a password to unlock protection (and permit editing)

So far I've found [this link](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/13/p/800/2032.aspx#2032) but it doesn't quite explain how to select what word/sentence/paragraph to protect

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems it works the opposite way. You need to restrict editing the full document, and to allow editing on all the other paragraphs using `w:permStart` and `w:permEnd`. http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/17/p/2686/8829.aspx